# During jailbreaking iPhone 4 shuts down and can't start again

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I have an iPhone 4 which I tried to install Cydia on, and everything worked well. However, when I tried to put it in DFU mode, it shuts down. I attempt to power it back up but nothing happens. What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try plugging in to computer then press the home and power button, it usually worked for me.

Comment: I agree, on this newest Evasi0n jailbreak I noticed that recovery mode works best if its already plugged in to the computer. Home and power button, release power when apple logo comes up and hold home button for another 8-10 seconds. It should connect then!

Answer (score 0):

It hasn't shut down - DFU mode displays a black screen, so you might think it has shut down. Go ahead and do whatever thing you wanted to do in DFU mode.